# Residue theorem and Laurent series?

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I want to evaluate this integral

$$ \oint \frac{z}{\sin z}\, dz$$

with the contour $C(2,3)$.

Do I change $\sin z$ into a Taylor series $ \int 1/h(z) dz$ where $h(z) = 1 -z^2/3!+...$ or is there a better way to calculate the residues at $0$ and $π$?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to calculate the residues at $z=0,\pi$?

Comment: Yes, sorry I will edit that

Comment: @EclipseSun It's removable at $0$.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt That's true. I just didn't notice that.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt oh so that would be Laurent's theorem at 0?

Comment: @LukeXu No. The residue at zero is zero, since it's a removable singularity. You only need to consider the reside at $z=\pi$. That's where you'll want to expand.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt That makes things so much easier. Thanks heaps!

Answer (score 1):

We are dealing here with simple poles. You could use

$$\operatorname{Res}(f,c)=\lim_{z\to c}(z-c)f(z)$$

or

$$\operatorname{Res}\left(\frac{g(z)}{f(z)},c\right) = \frac{g(c)}{f'(c)}$$

(where $f(c)=0$ is a simple pole, and $g(c)\neq 0$).

As noted, the pole at $z=0$ is removable, since $\lim_{z\to 0} \frac{z}{\sin z}=1$.

Comment: So the integral would be 2πi(res(f,0) + res(f,π)) = 2πi(1-π)

Comment: @LukeXu At zero, the residue is zero, because the singularity is removable. The other residue seems fine though.